# PHP prevent htmlspecialchars from converting numbers in URL

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I have this url which I need to pass to the browser and would like to encode it.  However I have numbers in the url string which also gets converted and thus causes issues.

Here is my string.

```
"http://domain.com/?w=132&h=132&zc=1&q=90&a=c"
```

And if i use htmlspecialchars, it would convert both 132 to 100 which is wrong.  How to prevent that?

UPDATE: perhaps I should mention that my string looks like that because I am using timthumb script.

Also I am not even sure if I need to encode anything?  or is the URL i provided safe?

Comment: i don't know how that happen to you, show the code how you did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you use urlencode instead?

`urlencode()`?
[PHP.net reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 3):

`htmlspecialchars` doesn't affect numbers... I have no idea what you're doing to get that...

Anyway, just pass it through [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode)

Answer (score 1):

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) only converts 5 characters:

```
'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

It doesn't touch numbers, letters, or other symbols.